# Fedora, apt-get & aptitude

Tags: linux, fedora, apt, aptitude

I am used to working on Ubuntu based systems. I have several DEBIAN repositories for distributing my software.

1. Now, I'd like to know if it is common for Fedora users to use "apt-get" and DEBIAN repositories?
2. What is the equivalent to Aptitude on Fedora based systems?

**Updated**: I understand the Fedora folks use yum. My question has more to do with "do folks bother with installing apt-get/aptitude to have access to stuff only available in DEB repositories? "

Comment: RedHat based distros use RPM, not DEB. And tools like YUM, up2date, yast

Comment: Regarding your edit: see my answer for a link to Alien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Hat, Fedora and their relatives use [RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager). They use [yum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified) for package management. OpenSuSE and SuSE use [Zypper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zypper).

[Alien](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/) converts packages between formats.

Comment: don't forget pacman/pkgbuild for arch and emerge/ebuild for gentoo

Comment: Yeah, I don't have first-hand experience with those systems, but I don't think emerge does binaries, does it?

Comment: Alien doesn't seem to be available through Yum by default: it seems to add to the "friction" I am afraid of i.e. folks on Fedora won't bother with a DEB repository.

Comment: Well, I was thinking more in terms of distributing the converted package rather than expecting the end-user to do it.

Comment: @Dennis:  right, I read you now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just experimenting, using apt to get things in Debian repos is a nice, quick & dirty way to get things running. it may or may not work well.

On a production system, you'd be crazy to do so... you're going to run into all sorts of dependency hell, break things, and spending alot of time for not much benefit -- you're better off building your own RPM if you enjoy pain or just building apps in your env.

Comment: although as a side note, using apt to grab sources for various debian packages might be worthwhile.... naturally you'd want to build your own RPMs for installation.

Answer (score 1):

Late hit addition: [apt4rpm](http://apt4rpm.sourceforge.net/) does exist but I would not count on it being installed; asking a user to install it is another hurdle to installing your application.

Having this tool on your own servers may not be a bad thing if you're used to the apt-get syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (and I haven't used fedora full time) it's yum. so man yum. dpkg and apt-get are a debian thing. the main difference between distro's is usually their package manager, imo.

and no, using fedora you would/should never use apt-get. you'd basically end up converting fedora into debian if you got it working.

Comment: that's not the point of my question really...

Answer (score 0):

While you can use apt-get in RPM distros the backend server that this is connecting to is one that serves RPMs not debs (Unless it is a completely custom install which most likely functions poorly). Typically combining packages from multiple distros is a bad idea even with alien et al because the applications are compiled with very specific shared library versions that are specific to the distro that is providing the packages. The only time it makes sense to use other package formats is when you are downloading a statically linked program that (more than likely) a company is distributing. Even then they usually have tarballs of just the statically linked application.

If you absolutely need an application that isn't available for your distro chances are the source is and you can create your own rpm/deb package, compiling it on your distro instead of hoping someone else's has enough in common with your distro that it works. While this is a bit more work, the hardest part is figuring it out for the first time.